# Can a markov chain have period of zero?

Tags: markov-chains

So i had an exam returned today, and im not convinced that my answer was wrong so it went like this.

[Markovian Chain Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF24p.jpg)

The question was if the the markov chain had a period (The correct answer is it has a period). And me looking at it, i was sure there was no period, but my classmates said that state E had a period of 0, Im not convinced with their answer, so I searched over the internet and i cant find samples of markov chains with period 0 because first of all it doesnt make sense, having a period would mean that the markov chain would return to the same state over some time, but if E had a period of 0 that would mean no transition is required for the state to return to E, but that is clearly not the case. Also the markov chain cannot have a period anywhere else, since there are many recurrent classes and even absorbing classes (period = 1 doesnt count because by definition period = 1 is aperiodic).

so i was thinking that maybe I overlooked something else, Im asking you guys which state here has a period

the teacher left early so i wasnt able to ask him about this so im asking you guys instead.

Comment: @JohnD It's not clear to me what your question is. Do you want to know why [the Markov chain in this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF24p.jpg) has a period, or do you actually want to know the question in the title (no, "period zero" makes no sense)?

Comment: "Can a markov chain have period of zero?" is my question, I'm curious if there anything to that end. Probably not since period only exists for irreducible classes

Answer (score 0):

Any Markov chain with a state that has a self-loop is aperiodic.

Answer (score 0):

The period of a markov chain is d = $hcf\{n~|~f_n >0\}$, where $f_n = p(T_i =n)$ is the probability of returning to a particular state in $n$ steps. Hence, it always has a period, it's just that if $d = 1$, we refer to it as aperiodic. But it still has a period, by definition.